# Calling static member function on an object-- is there a way to make that into compiler error?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, compilation, static-methods

It is annoying that the IDE will auto-complete static methods when other methods act as modifiers to the object. Is there an (intelligent) way of making code like the below into a compilation error?

```
  // Translate along X and Y axes, rotate pi/4 about axis X;
  QQuaternion q;
  q.fromAxisAndAngle({1,0,0}, 45.0); // whoops, fromAxisAndAngle is static!
  // Later: test fails, "wait why is my quaternion still identity!?"
```

Perhaps some kind of check on the return value of static method being ignored AND it's invoked on an object `ClassFoo().StaticMethod()` rather than through `ClassFoo::StaticMethod()` ?

Comment: _"It is annoying that the IDE ..."_ Which IDE actually? There's a lot of!

Comment: No because it isn't an error.

Comment: In a word: no. It's valid C++ syntax. If your compiler issues a warning in this case, it may be possible to mark the warning as an error.  Why do you care?

Answer (score 1):

You can't distinguish the "invoked on an object" case in your code because it's just a syntactical device. The result of the call is the same regardless. But a given compiler might support a warning diagnostic on this, and if so, it might be possible to turn that warning diagnostic into a compilation error (e.g., with g++, `-pedantic-errors`, but I don't know if g++ has a warning for that call).

Comment: Or just `-Werror` which turns *all* warnings into errors ;)